# remove selected ticks on axis

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, plot

In **`Matplotlib`**, on the **`Y axis`** I have values in `[0, 1]`, but the Y axis goes up to `1.2`.

Now, that extra **`blank space`** is very handy and I'd like to keep it, but I don't want that `1.2` to show up on the Y-axis range.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You could "[prune](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MaxNLocator)" the top ytick:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# ... your plotting code here ...
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(prune='upper'))
```

Excerpt from the excellent documentation: "If `prune=='upper'`, the largest tick will be removed."

---

Edit: If there are more ticks to remove, or if you prefer having more control over the maximum number of ticks, use the `nbins` kwarg:

```
...
max_num_of_intervals = 5
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(nbins=max_num_of_intervals))
```